# Jquery each loop not working?

Tags: jquery, each

```
$(':submit').click(function(e) {
    $('.requiredField :input').each(function() {
        if ('input[type=text]'){
            if($(this).val().length === 0) {
                $(this).addClass('warning'); //
                var errorMsg = $('<br /> Please Fill all the Fields').addClass('warning');
                errorMsg.insertAfter('.requiredField .textbox');
            }
        }
    });
    e.preventDefault(); //preventing form submission
});
```

All i need from this function is to give error message on each empty textboxes but it instead does something like:
if i have two empty textboxes it gives error on all the textboxes x 2? Help please?

Comment: `if ('input[type=text]'){` will always be true. What did you intend for it to test? currently it just tests if the string is true, but it will always be true since it isn't empty. You could probably just remove that if statement.

Comment: Did you mean `if($(this).is("input[type=text]")){`?

Comment: i want to check if the textboxes are empty? so if you see the next line i am checking if its length is 0 and if it is create a br and add a error msg

Comment: Also, you really should move e.preventDefault() to the top, you want to prevent the default action as soon as possible so that a js error doesn't prevent you from getting to that line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Your initial check of `if ('input[type=text]'){` doesn't really make sense.
2. The line:

   `errorMsg.insertAfter('.requiredField .textbox');`

   will insert your error message after every instance of that class. You probably want something more along the lines of:

   `errorMsg.insertAfter(this);`

   I can't say for certain what you need without seeing the HTML, but I can guarantee that what you have is NOT what you actually want.

Comment: My form also has checkboxes and radio buttons so i am checking if input type is text then check its length and if its empty break that line and add an error message?if you understand what i mean?

Comment: It doesn't make sense meaning that that line of code does NOT do what you think it does. See the top-level comment from Jan Dvorak.

Comment: i would of showed my problem but it does not allow me to post an image at the moment?

Comment: thanks david ...i was doing it wrong finally corrected it. insertAfter(this) worked.